# Relativistic conservation of momentum in an elastic collision

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I am reading from Townsend's Quantum Physics (not Mechanics).

In frame $S'$ there are two masses of mass $m$ that elastically collide along the $x$-axis. The masses rebound perpendicular to their original direction of motion after the collision.

In frame $S$ moving in the $-x$ direction at speed $V$ w.r.t. $S'$, one of the masses that was moving in frame $S'$ is now at rest. The other mass is moving at speed $v_x = \frac{2V}{1+V^2/c^2}$. The masses post collision both have x-components of velocity $V$.

It's observed that $mv_x \neq 2mV$, motivating a new definition of momentum: $p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$. It is said by Townsend that using this definition of momentum in frame S should result in a conservation of momentum.

In particular, I tried showing that:

$$\frac{mv_x}{\sqrt{1-v_x^2/c^2}} = \frac{2mV}{\sqrt{1-V^2/c^2}}.$$

Which can be manipulated into:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/v_x^2-1/c^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1/V^2-1/c^2}}.$$

Which is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/(\frac{2V}{1+V^2/c^2})^2-1/c^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1/V^2-1/c^2}}.$$

Which is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/(\frac{2V}{1+V^2/c^2})^2-1/c^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1/V^2-1/c^2}}.$$

Which is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/(\frac{4V^2}{(1+V^2/c^2)^2})-1/c^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1/V^2-1/c^2}}.$$

However, I have been trying for hours to work it out to no avail. Can someone help me understand how momentum is conserved using the provided relationships in frame S?

Comment: You've been trying for hours with what work? You should show what you've tried.

Comment: The equality I started with is provided.

Comment: What I mean is you stated you've tried for hours, so you should show everything you tried to do to show this equality.